# Make a list from http responsebody in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, xmlhttprequest

If i use this code below, i can get `responseJson`

```
import 'dart:async'; 
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchPost() async {
  var params = {
    "serviceKey": Uri.encodeFull("t8iGBTBFQc5nMq9ytuMZQ7jxR8ZMzohG/5o0i80f+ehjFhMpkADfArAvFk+jHsPMFFEThQgejzujdpfou/DWng=="), // Uri.encodeFull을 쓰면 자동으로 utf-8로 encoded 됨.
    "cityCode": Uri.encodeFull("25"),
    "nodeId": Uri.encodeFull("DJB8001793ND"),
  };

  Uri uri = Uri.parse('http://openapi.tago.go.kr/openapi/service/ArvlInfoInqireService/getSttnAcctoArvlPrearngeInfoList'); // URI 지정.
  final newURI = uri.replace(queryParameters: params);

  final response = await http.get(
    newURI,
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
    },
  );

  final responseJson = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    debugPrint('$responseJson'); // For testing
    return responseJson;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load post');
  }

}
```

and the contents of `responseJosn` is this.

```
{response: {header: {resultCode: 00, resultMsg: NORMAL SERVICE.}, body: {items: {item: [{arrprevstationcnt: 1, arrtime: 146, nodeid: DJB8001793ND, nodenm: 송강전통시장, routeid: DJB30300002ND, routeno: 2, routetp: 급행버스, vehicletp: 일반차량}, {arrprevstationcnt: 12, arrtime: 879, nodeid: DJB8001793ND, nodenm: 송강전통시장, routeid: DJB30300004ND, routeno: 5, routetp: 마을버스, vehicletp: 일반차량}, {arrprevstationcnt: 3, arrtime: 220, nodeid: DJB8001793ND, nodenm: 송강전통시장, routeid: DJB30300054ND, routeno: 301, routetp: 간선버스, vehicletp: 일반차량}, {arrprevstationcnt: 9, arrtime: 737, nodeid: DJB8001793ND, nodenm: 송강전통시장, routeid: DJB30300093ND, routeno: 802, routetp: 간선버스, vehicletp: 일반차량}]}, numOfRows: 10, pageNo: 1, totalCount: 4}}}
```

So what i have been trying to do is make a list of
items.
For example,

item[0] will have this information
`{arrprevstationcnt: 1, arrtime: 146, nodeid: DJB8001793ND, nodenm: 송강전통시장, routeid: DJB30300002ND, routeno: 2, routetp: 급행버스, vehicletp: 일반차량}`

item[1] will have this information
`{arrprevstationcnt: 12, arrtime: 879, nodeid: DJB8001793ND, nodenm: 송강전통시장, routeid: DJB30300004ND, routeno: 5, routetp: 마을버스, vehicletp: 일반차량}`

So i can easily use item[0][1] = 146, if i want to use `arrtime` of first item.

Even though i made this code,

```
class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<Map<String, dynamic>> post; 

  TestScreen({Key key, this.post}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Fetch Data Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child:
          FutureBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>>(
            future: post,
            builder: (context, snapshot) { 
              if (snapshot.hasData) { 
                return Text(
                    "${snapshot.data.values.toList()[0]["body"]["items"]["item"]
                    [0][x] // x can be like "arrtime"
                    }"
                ); 
              }
              else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("${snapshot.error}");
              }
              // By default, show a loading spinner.
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I realize it is difficult to use FutureBuilder for various screen and widgets.
So is there any solutions for this? thanks for reading my question.

Comment: i will recommend this post from Pooja https://medium.com/flutter-community/working-with-apis-in-flutter-8745968103e9 working with Future builder its not hard, but you are skipping some important parts and the way you are working, withour any models, this will give you more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
var responseValues = Map.from(responseJson).values.toList()[0]["body"]["items"]["item"];
print("${responseValues}");
```

result:

```
[{arrprevstationcnt: 4, arrtime: 269, nodeid: DJB8001793ND, nodenm: 송강전통시장, routeid: DJB30300002ND, routeno: 2, routetp: 급행버스, vehicletp: 저상버스}, {arrprevstationcnt: 0, arrtime: 97, nodeid: DJB8001793ND, nodenm: 송강전통시장, routeid: DJB30300004ND, routeno: 5, routetp: 마을버스, vehicletp: 일반차량}, {arrprevstationcnt: 5, arrtime: 435, nodeid: DJB8001793ND, nodenm: 송강전통시장, routeid: DJB30300054ND, routeno: 301, routetp: 간선버스, vehicletp: 저상버스}, {arrprevstationcnt: 3, arrtime: 201, nodeid: DJB8001793ND, nodenm: 송강전통시장, routeid: DJB30300093ND, routeno: 802, routetp: 간선버스, vehicletp: 일반차량}]
```